# Acces Android UI elemnts from inside static AsyncTask method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So I'm trying to create an app that syncs files over an ssh connection. The ssh connection is started as an AsyncTask and I would like it to set the text of a UI element inside the onPostExecute method, but can't seem to declare or use the necessary variables inside of it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView infoView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoView);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new sshConnectTask().execute();
    }

    static class sshConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){
            /*STUFF*/
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            infoView.setText("ASD");
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I would like to call infoView.setText() inside the onPostExecute method.

**UPDATE**
Someone on Discord helped me fixed it:

1. setContentView has to be called before findViewByID; otherwise findViewById just returns mull
2. the infoView variable can be passed to the SSHConnectTask like

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       TextView infoView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoView);
       new SSHConnectTask(infoView).execute();
   }
   ```
3. Then SSHConnectTask has to be adapted

   ```
   static class SSHConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
       private TextView display;

       public SSHConnectTask(TextView display){
           this.display = display;
       }
   ```

After that infoViews text can be set in onPostExecute with

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    display.setText("TEST");
```

Comment: move `TextView infoView` out of `oncreate`

Comment: Hey, I edited my code and post but it doesn't change the the problem.

Comment: This is a hook because I'll need a real keyboard for answering this question

Answer (score 1):

Using WeakReference when calling asynchronous code is kind of a hack, what you should do is use the Android Architecture Components released last year (2017) which let you simplify this sort of thing.

So you have an activity that observes data in a viewmodel:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView infoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        infoView = findViewById(R.id.infoView);
        MainViewModel mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
        mainViewModel.infoText.observe(this, (text) -> {
            infoView.setText(text);
        });
    }
}
```

And you should create a ViewModel where this sort of connection is handled inside a LiveData that is stored in the ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {
    LiveData<String> infoText = new InfoTextLiveData();

    public MainViewModel() {
    }
}
```

And your LiveData should know how to fetch the data:

```
public class InfoTextLiveData extends MutableLiveData<String> {
    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        new SshConnectTask().execute(); // optionally, you could `cancel()` the asyncTask in `onInactive()`
    }

    class SshConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){
            /*STUFF*/
            postValue("ASD");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

For this, you have to add the AAC dependencies:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

and

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
```

---

For more info, refer to the guide:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! It almost works but I can't seem to find the ViewModelProviders object. There is ViewModelProvider (no s), but it has no .of method.

Comment: Hrmm according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders it says it should have a static method called `of` and it should work if you extend AppCompatActivity

Comment: Your link does say it's deprecated and that ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory should be used instead. But that doesn't have on of method either.

Comment: No it says `new ViewModelProviders()` is deprecated. `ViewModelProviders.of(appCompatActivity)` should work

Comment: But I can't import ViewModelProviders, so I can't use it's method.

Comment: Did you add the dependencies to your gradle file like I mentioned? If yes, then maybe I missed something and can check Specifically if something is missing. But it should have everything as per https://github.com/Zhuinden/mvvm-aac-rxjava-retrofit-room/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: I had the repositories, where should I add the implementation and annotationProcessor lines?

Comment: In the other `build.gradle`'s `dependencies {` block

Answer (score 0):

first declare `TextView infoView` as class variable instead of as method variable.
Secondly I highly doubt that a static class can access instance variables since there could be two instances of `MainActivity` so there would also be two `infoView`.
You  either need to make `infoView` static or remove static from `sshConnectTask`

Comment: Hey, even after I changed it I get an error saying that it can't be referenced from a static context. I can't declare it as static since findViewById(R.id.infoView) can not be referenced from a static context.
I can't *really* remove the ssh connection either since that's really the only thing I need from his app.

Comment: Well I just pointed out all possible solutions and while it's a bad solution it actually works :/ aaaand also I'm incredibly bad with memory leaks :D

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that the TextView will still be alive (not garbage collected) when the AsyncTask is finished doing its background task.

I think what you should do is create an interface called something like ResultListener and make your Activity implement it. Then when creating the AsyncTask, pass your Activity (this) into the constructor of the Async task, but keep it as a [WeakReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).

```
public interface ResultListener<T> {
    setResult(T result);
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ResultListener<String> {

    @Override
    public void setResult(String result) {
         infoView.setText(result);
    }

    public TextView infoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        infoView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoView);
        new sshConnectTask(this).execute();
    }

    static class sshConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private WeakReference<ResultListener> listener;
        public sshConnectTask(ResultListener resultListener) {
            listener = new WeakReference<>(resultListener);
        }

        ...

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ResultListener listener = this.listener.get();
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.setResult(result);
            } 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't actually override or implement setResult properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could drop the static from keyword from your AsyncTask, but then you will get a warning that it may cause a leak.  The leak could occur if the Activity is destroyed while the task is running since a non-static inner class holds a reference to it's enclosing class.  Alternatively, you could try passing the textview to the AsyncTask like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView infoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    infoView = findViewById(R.id.infoView);
    new sshConnectTask(infoView).execute();
}

static class sshConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    WeakReference<TextView> weakTextView;

    sshConnectTask(TextView view){
        weakTextView = new WeakReference<>(view);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){
        /*STUFF*/
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        TextView infoText = weakTextView.get();
        if(infoText != null) {
            infoText.setText("ASD");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I get this error if I try to pass infoView to sshConnectTask:


    `error: constructor sshConnectTask in class sshConnectTask cannot 
    be applied to given types;
    required: no arguments
    found: TextView
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`