# Avoid memory leak with WeakReference Android

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have this code example below and i want to make sure that no memory will happen. By passing the whole activity to an async task will lead to a memory leak if the task itself will have a bigger lifecycle than activity's. But if i declare a weakReference, means that if a rotation is about to happen, the activity will be destroyed without memory leak. Am right guys? Do i have to set something to null also?

Main .java

```
public class Main extends Activity {

  private TextView mMessageView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView();

    new Background(this /*getBaseContext()*/ ).execute();
  }
}
```

Background.java

```
 public class Background extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    private WeakReference activity;

    public void Background(Activity act)
    {
          activity = new WeakReference(act);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {  
            if(activity.get()!=null)
            //ToDo
    }
}
```

Comment: A better option is to not execute AsyncTask inside Activity. Check out ViewModel + LiveData for this. See the discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395053/acces-android-ui-elemnts-from-inside-static-asynctask-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for explicit nulling when using WeakReference. Regarding the use of AsyncTask inside an Activity, just be careful not to create an anonymous instance because it will have an implicit reference to the enclosing class which can lead to memory leaks.

The code you posted seems ok, don't forget to terminate the AsyncTask gracefully when the activity is recreated.